# RaspPi and PostgreSQL

Tags: raspbian

Can I use my raspberry pi as a PostgreSQL database which I can use for the metasploit framework.

So normaly (for example on the kali linux distro) you have to create a postgreSQL database on your device and connect this to metasploit with the command `db_connect`.

Again the question: can I use my raspberry pi as a PostgreSQL database for metasploit usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1` to install PostgreSQL.

Also, if you don't want to install tools on raspbian, I suggest you to get image of kali linux for Rpi. Link : http://docs.kali.org/kali-on-arm/install-kali-linux-arm-raspberry-pi

Comment: Thanks, but how can I connect to it then just somethinglike: `msf> db_connect "ip of Rpi"` ?

Comment: @MaricioJongma I believe that you need to change database.yml file in order to set those parameter. Have a look at this link. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Metasploit_Postgres_Setup Make sure your Rpi db is accessible from its ip and you have exact same users, db etc on your Rpi db. Good luck.